# why java simpledateformat parse method does not support timezone id

Tags: java, parsing, simpledateformat

java's `SimpleDateFormat` `parse` method supports timezone short name, long name and offset.
Why support for timezone Id is not given??

For eg.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("z");
sdf.parse("IST");                       //works fine

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("z");
sdf.parse("Indian Standard Time");      //Also works fine
```

Why java doesn't support this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("z");
sdf.parse("Asia/Kolkata");              //does not work
```

Answer (score 2):

We shoud ask JDK developers why they decided that SimpleDateFormat should not support timezone Id. Also SimpleDateFormat API is not clear what timezone format it expects for 'z'. But I know what it supports. It checks timezone against data returned by DateFormatSymbols.getZoneStrings(). It is an array of timezones, each timezone is an array of Strings

```
    •[0] - time zone ID
    •[1] - long name of zone in standard time
    •[2] - short name of zone in standard time
    •[3] - long name of zone in daylight saving time
    •[4] - short name of zone in daylight saving time
```

The zone ID is not localized; others are localized names. See API for details.

We can get all avaliable timezones as

```
    DateFormatSymbols dfs = DateFormatSymbols.getInstance();
    for(String[] s : dfs.getZoneStrings()) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
    }
```

result (it depends on locale)

```
...
[Asia/Calcutta, India Standard Time, IST, India Daylight Time, IDT]
...
```

So SimpleDateFormat (in my locale) allows India Standard Time, IST, India Daylight Time or IDT for 'z', but it does not allow Asia/Calcutta (Timezone ID)

Answer (score 2):

If you use Java 8 you can use new Date and Time API. "VV" means a timezone ID.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Example:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm VV");
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("06/23/2015 21:00 US/Pacific", formatter);
```